# Logging Slf4j in Tomcat Server for cosole logs

Tags: java, eclipse, slf4j, tomcat8

[image][image]I have created a webbapp which runs on Tomcat 8.5 from Eclipse.
I am using slf4j logger.
I have added some log statements(INFO/DEBUG) in the code and I can see them on Eclipse console output when I start Tomcat from eclipse.

Now I export the code as a war and deployed it to installed Tomcat /webapps folder and restarted the server.
Upon checking the catalina.logs , I can see the Tomcat startup logs .

1. But upon the hitting the war(url), console log statements(INFO/DEBUG) are not showing up in catalina.logs ?
2. Which Log should I check for console error.??

I am new to Tomcat. Am I missing some additional configuration here???

I haven't made any changes in the logging.properties

Comment: can you post your logging.properties file

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/685806